# Rails errors NOT showing up in f.error_messages, but in errors they are

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have errors in a model that **are** showing up in the view when accessed with @model.errors. However, they do **not** show up if I try to do

```
  <%form_for @applicant do |f|%>
      <%=f.error_messages%> 
      This is zero, freakily: <%=f.error_messages.length%> 
      But this is not: <%=@applicant.errors.length%>
```

however, the errors are present if I do

```
@applicant.errors.each
```

Any suggestions as to where I should look to resolve this? It's absolutely strange...

The form is working perfectly otherwise.

**Edit:** Thanks to ScottD's answer I figured out what was happening. I had simplified the question here on SO, but that was the problem. I was **really** doing this:

```
<%form_for @applicant.thinger do |f|%>
```

and therein lies the problem. The error_messages_for method that the form_helper calls needs the thing to be one level deep (meaning an instance variable like @applicant, which it then translates to :applicant, and never like @applicant.status). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example f is not the @applicant object, it is the Form builder object.  What you want is something like:

```
<%= error_messages_for 'applicant' %>
```

See the [Rails API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper.html#M001694).

Comment: +1 That worked, however it makes no sense to me. I always use f.error_messages and it always works. As it says here, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html you can use the FormBuilder instance to get the errors.

Comment: I mean, thank you for that, if you have any suggestions as to why it wouldn't work with f I'd like to know please.

Comment: I answered my own question in the question, above, and thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.... This worked for me

```
<% if @applicant.errors.any? %>
    <% @applicant.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <%= msg %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```